# Why does Serial.print print only a value for 0-84 for a 100 integer array?

Tags: array

```
int a[100],i;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
    a[i] = i;
    Serial.println(a[i]);
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 27):

It's because you're using `exit(0)`.  That turns off interrupts and goes into an infinite loop. However, serial printing is first placed into a buffer, and each character is then removed from that buffer in turn and sent out through the serial port.

That's all fine, up until the end when you use `exit(0);`, and what is left in the serial buffer to send never gets sent because interrupts are disabled.

There is never really any cause to use `exit()` on a microcontroller - after all, where can it "exit" to? There's no OS to exit to. So it does the next best thing which is as close to doing nothing as reasonably possible.

Instead, if you want to "stop" your program you should use a simple `while(1);` which will allow interrupts to still trigger.

Alternatively, if you really want to use `exit()`, you should `flush` the serial first:

```
Serial.flush();
```

That function will block until the transmit buffer has been fully emptied by the interrupt and the last byte has left the UART's TX shift register.

Comment: And from [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/1727/45942) (assuming more than 1000 bytes of RAM) the UART's buffer will be 64 bytes, which is just enough to hold the remaining 15 numbers (two bytes + CR + LF each) with four bytes left over.

Comment: I wouldn't say that one shouldn't call `exit()` on a microcontroller. Rather, one shouldn't call a simple infinite loop `exit()`, suggesting it's a proper POSIX function.